# Two subsequences diverge to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively...

Tags: limits

Let $\{a_n\}(n=1,2,\cdots)$ be a sequence. It has one subsequence diverging to $+\infty$ and another subsequence diverging to $-\infty$. What conclusion can be drawn from these conditions on the convergence or divergence of $\{a_n\}$?

At least, we may know that $a_n$ can not converge to a finite limit,namely a concrete real number,say $a$. Otherwise, all of the subsequences must tend to $a$, which contradicts the assumptions above. But can we infer $a_n \to \infty$?

Comment: Hint: consider the sequence $a_{n} = (-1)^{n}n$.

Comment: What does $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ mean ? Does that mean that $a_n \rightarrow + \infty$ or $a_n \rightarrow - \infty$ ? Or something else ?

Comment: @DMcMor Your $a_n \to \infty$.

Comment: No it doesn't. $\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^nn$ is undefined.

Comment: You can infer $|a_n|\to\infty$.

Comment: @PeterForeman $\forall M>0$,$\exists N=[M]+1 \in \mathbb{N}:|a_n|=n>M$ holds for $n>N$.

Comment: Yes you can define the limit of $|(-1)^nn|$ but not of $(-1)^nn$ itself. What you just wrote states that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|=+\infty\ne \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Answer (score 1):

We say a real sequence $\{a_n\}$ tends to infinity as $n \to \infty$, if

> $ \forall  M > 0 \space \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \space \forall n\geq N: \space a_n > M $.

Similarly, we say a real sequence $\{a_n\}$ tends to $-\infty$ as $n \to \infty$, if

> $ \forall  M < 0 \space \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \space \forall n\geq N: \space a_n < M $.

The existence of a subsequence $\{a_{n_{k}}\}$ tending to $\infty$ and the existence of a subsequence $\{a_{n_{l}}\}$ tending to $-\infty$, imply that for any real number $M$ and any choice of positive integer $N$ we can find members of the sequence $\{a_n\}$, with $n \geq N$, which are above $M$ and we can also find members, with $n \geq N$, which are below $M$.

Therefore, by the above definitions, $\{a_n\}$ does **not** tend to $\infty$ and does **not** tend to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

No we cannot infer that $a_n\to\infty$. The limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$
would be undefined as the sequence is not Cauchy.